# bash: passing format information into printf

Tags: bash, printf

Iv'e got a script with a generalized usage/error function, that prints the error out and then gives the script usage information.   I reduced that for purposes of discussion to this example:

```
usage() {
  test -n "$1" && printf "\n %s" "$1" >&2
}

usage "Error:  text1 \ntext2 \ntext3"
```

This produces the output:

```
Error:  text1 \ntext2 \ntext3
```

I wanted each set of text to be on a separate line.  How do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `%b` format:

```
usage() { [[ $@ ]] && printf "%b\n" "$@"; }
```

and call it as:

```
usage "Error:  text1 \ntext2 \ntext3"
```

**Output:**

```
Error:  text1
text2
text3
```

As per `help printf`:

```
%b  expand backslash escape sequences in the corresponding argument
```

Comment: I've got an error code I'm passing into the function too, so I don't think I can do the $@, right.   Why'd you change it from $1?

Comment: Because I wanted to allow multiple arguments also in to this function. But you can certainly use: `usage() { [[ $1 ]] && printf "%b\n" "$1"; }` to make it single argument print only.
`

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your comment.  I think you need a few more points than 287K though ... what have you been up to ... lazing around?

Answer (score 3):

You can process the escape sequences when creating the literal that you pass as an argument, by using `$'...'` syntax.

```
usage $'Error:  text1 \ntext2 \ntext3'
```

See [ANSI-C Quoting](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting)

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the format string:

```
usage() {
  [[ -n "$1" ]] && printf "$1" >&2
}

usage "Error:  text1 \ntext2 \ntext3"
```

Comment: I see, then I can't have any other formatting in that printf, but I could do another printf before or after, right?

Comment: @Ray: If that other formatting is relevant to your question, please include it in your example. You might have reduced it a bit too much.

Comment: @Ray I don't get what other format you would want to print. Can you give an example? Since you are printing only $1, I assumed you are just interested in newline expansion.

Comment: This is actually error prone. Try calling `usage '%pqr'`

Comment: No, I think what you put will work.  Am comparing/testing both answers now.  Not sure why @anubhava changed his answer to use $@ instead of $1

Comment: You are right, am only interested in printing newline information.

Comment: Thank you @Blue Moon.   I'm awarding both answers one point, and marking his as the more "correct" one, per my general "pass format question".  Thanks again.

Comment: @anubhava That's true if the string would contain various format strings. But it was not clear to me and OP says he's only interested in newlines.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear but if you want a `usage` function that puts each argument on its own line you could use this instead:

```
$ usage() {
    printf %s\\n "$@" >&2
}
$ usage 'Error:  text1' text2 text3
Error:  text1
text2
text3
```

or do the loop yourself and keep `usage` from outputting anything on empty arguments:

```
usage() {
    for arg; do
        printf %s\\n "$arg" >&2
    done
}
```

or to borrow a trick from anubhava's answer:

```
usage() {
    [[ "$@" ]] && printf %s\\n "$@" >&2
}
```

or without the `[[` bashism:

```
usage() {
    [ -n "$*" ]] && printf %s\\n "$@" >&2
}
```